# Error Unrecognized xmltree line on line 20: 'C: " "' when trying to publish my app on Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, release

I'm facing this error message when I try to send the new apk version of my App to google play:

> Not possible to analyse your APK using aapt. Exit error: Unrecognized
>   xmltree line on line 20: 'C: "    "'

Anyone have any idea of whats going on? I searched around on google and here but I didn't find nothing.

Comment: Small grammar changes and format error

Comment: Any luck on this, I'm facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems their check got way more strict and is rejecting odd chars in whitespaces.

For us it was a wired unicode char that was in the whitespace between the xml elements. It was not visible in IntelliJ and it was also not visible in the error given by Google.

I found it by opening the manifest file in TextMate (I'm on Mac) but every other editor that allowed you to find/see non printable unicode chars is also good.

Comment: Thanks, i found it! It was indeed some whitespaces on the wrong place in the Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I got a same issue with you.

In my case,

> Not possible to analyse your APK using aapt. Exit error: Unrecognized xmltree line on line 1010: 'C: "\n\n"'

I decoded my apk files using aapt and get AndroidManifest.xml from apk.
So that I can find what the problem is.

Specific line did line break, but I don't know why.
Moreover, I upload the apk that I successfully uploaded before, it calls same error too.

I really don't know why and all I found is yours. There is no issue about this problem.

I requested this problem too google, so if I receive the answer i'll let you know.

If you got solution, plz let me know too. If I got it, I'll tell you too.

Comment: Still having the problem here too. If i have some progress, i will post here too.

Comment: Take a look on @Andreass Rossbacher anwser, it solved the problem for me. I had some whitespaces missplaced on mine AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Oh yay. In similiar ways, i delete all of the codes where the problem is occured, then re-write the sentence. And, i don’t know why, error has gone. Anyway, it’s nice to solve it both of us.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play parsing of the app has got much more strict. If you want to try something that is close to similarly strict you can try using [`aapt2`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) which comes with the Android SDK or can be downloaded as part of the [build tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools).

Then commands like `aapt2 dump your.apk` will give you some errors.